# Cant Re-install Mac os x 10.10

Tags: usb-flash-drive, osx-lion, macbook-pro, reinstall

Last night i factory reset my mums mums MacBook pro.
 I had got to the point where I had to re install mac os x. I selected the hard drive I wanted it on and it prompted me with a apple id sign in. I knew from then that my or my mothers apple Id wasn't going to work because my mum told me she had got it off trade me ( like ebay but in NZ ) 
I've tried making a bootable usb drive to re install lion os x but it didn't work, or I just didn't do it right. Its a MacBook Pro 2010 mid I think and I am stumped on what to do, now that it has no operating system on it or anything on it now, only thing that works is the utilities mode. 
All help is very appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: isn't there supposed to be a way to install the OS via recovery mode? Something like cmd+shift+R when it boots?

Comment: If you are not sure with the mail id then contact apple support with your purchase bill. They will reset your mail id then you can use new one.

Comment: @Blaine Yes, there should be a recovery partition, though at this time i can't remember if it needs a sign-in or not.

Comment: @vembutech You shouldn't even need to go that far. You should be able to access Apple's website from another machine and reset the mom's AppleID that way.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf - Resetting the ID isn't the aim, nor will it achieve anything. You can only a) install from Recovery to the OS that was currently on the machine or b) as Ecnerwal says below, boot to Internet Recovery & install the OS that the machine first shipped with.

Comment: @Tetsujin Of course! But one of the things the OP mentioned was "it prompted me with an Apple sign in, and that didn't work". So, if they could get to another device to reset that password, OP's original process could theoretically work.

Comment: No, the password will never work at that point. If the OS is wiped, there's 'no owner' at that point & you cannot install anything except the 'no sign-in' OS, which is the one it shipped with. Even though it may prompt, anything other than the original OS will show as 'not available at the moment'.

Comment: @Tetsujin Aha, I did not know that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

[Option-CMD-R](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904) on startup should get you to the OS that shipped with your Mac. You may want to reformat the drive first. The behavior changes at 10.12, but you didn't start there, so it should do that for your 10.10 system.

From memory - getting the "latest version installed on your mac" reinstalled took the sign-in process (and didn't work even with the right sign-in, IIRC) while reverting to the original was done without requiring a sign-in (and then you can update with the current sign-in.)

Comment: Then how would I reinstall an older version of mac os x ?